# mvc4 Websecurity.login exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

When I call `"WebSecurity.Login("UserName","Password",persistCookie:false)"`

The below exception flows

> To call this method, the “Membership.Provider” property must be an instance of “ExtendedMembershipProvider”

Here's the code to initialize the connection:

```
private class SimpleMembershipInitializer
        {
            public SimpleMembershipInitializer()
            {
                    WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("defaultDB", "User", "Id", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
            }
        }
```

And below is the configuration file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->

<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add connectionString="source = 192.168.1.100; initial catalog=tempDB; user=sa; pwd=123; integrated security = true" name="defaultDB" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="true" />
  </appSettings>

  <system.web>
    <roleManager enabled="true"/>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />

    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />

    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />

    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <qualifyAssembly partialName="WebMatrix.WebData" fullName="WebMatrix.WebData, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>

</configuration>
```

Why the above exception flows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setting following line of code in your `web.config` :

```
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="SimpleRoleProvider">
        <providers>
            <clear />
            <add name="SimpleRoleProvider" type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleRoleProvider, WebMatrix.WebData" />
        </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <membership defaultProvider="SimpleMembershipProvider">
        <providers>
            <clear />
            <add name="SimpleMembershipProvider" type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider, WebMatrix.WebData" />
        </providers>
    </membership>
    <sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
        <providers>
            <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" />
        </providers>
    </sessionState>
```

Comment: an exception shows after I added this into the config file: Can not read configuration section 'roleManager', because of missing declarations, how to solve this?

Comment: put that inside `<system.web>`

Comment: oh it worked..but one more question: Where should I specify the Password for the "WebSecurity.Login"? I can only declare the Database, login table name and username.

Comment: if you enable migration you can seed membership and add users and roles : `membership.CreateUserAndAccount("user", "123456");`